# petite chez scheme interpreter in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, scheme, chez-scheme

I installed the "schemeway" plugin in eclipse and now i need an interpreter.

I'm trying to set the "petite chez scheme" interpreter on eclipse but with no success.

i tried to fill the boxes with the name of the interpreter and set the "Working Directory" to be the installation directory but it's not good.

can someone explain me what should i fill in the boxes in the picture?

[image]

thank you guys :)